# Removing Json object name using Logtash

Tags: json, log4j, logstash, logstash-jdbc, logstash-json

I'm trying to parse the following json using logstash

```
   {
    "payload": "{\"class\":\"OpenLoyalty\\\\Component\\\\Account\\\\Domain\\\\Event\\\\PointsTransferHasBeenExpired\",\"payload\":{\"accountId\":\"1cbd42b8-1b1f-4a13-a28f-eefeb73a64b0\",\"pointsTransferId\":\"e82c96cf-32a3-43bd-9034-4df343e5f111\"}}"
}
```

using this filter :

```
    input {
        jdbc {
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/openloyalty"
            jdbc_user => "openloyalty"
            jdbc_password => "openloyalty"
            jdbc_driver_library => "C:\logstash\postgresql-42.2.12.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
            statement => "SELECT payload from events where events.id=130;"
        }
    }
    filter {
          json {
            source => "payload"
            remove_field => ["class"]
          }

    }
    output {
        stdout { codec => json_lines }
    }
```

I get this output:

```
    {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2020-05-12T11:27:15.097Z",
    "payload": {
        "accountId": "1cbd42b8-1b1f-4a13-a28f-eefeb73a64b0",
        "pointsTransferId": "e82c96cf-32a3-43bd-9034-4df343e5f111"
    }
   }
```

however, what I'm looking for is like this:

```
{
"@version": "1",
"@timestamp": "2020-05-12T11:27:15.097Z",
 {
    "accountId": "1cbd42b8-1b1f-4a13-a28f-eefeb73a64b0",
    "pointsTransferId": "e82c96cf-32a3-43bd-9034-4df343e5f111"
 }
}
```

how can I remove the "payload" name from my Json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mutate` filter with the following config after your `json` filter.

```
mutate {
    rename => {
        "[payload][accountId]" => "accountId"
        "[payload][pointsTransferId]" => "pointsTransferId"
    }
    remove_field => ["[payload]"]
}
```

This will rename your fields and remove the empty `payload` json object after the rename.

Comment: that works absolutely fine, but I'm afraid I may have more complex values in my payload. I mean it seems so hard to rename all the fields. is there another way?

Comment: You could try to add another `json` filter with the source also as `payload` after the first one. Your first `json` filter will parse the `payload` message, which is the result of your query, your second `json` filter will parse the nested `payload` field, which is inside your `payload` message.

Comment: I tried this solution but I get this : ```{
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => 2020-05-13T10:21:13.807Z,
       "payload" => {
               "accountId" => "1cbd42b8-1b1f-4a13-a28f-eefeb73a64b0",
        "pointsTransferId" => "e82c96cf-32a3-43bd-9034-4df343e5f111"
    },
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
    ]
}```

Comment: and this is the error that I'm facing : ```Error parsing json {:source=>"payload", :raw=>{"accountId"=>"1cbd42b8-1b1f-4a13-a28f-eefeb73a64b0", "pointsTransferId"=>"e82c96cf-32a3-43bd-9034-4df343e5f111"}, :exception=>java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jruby.RubyHash cannot be cast to org.jruby.RubyIO}```